# Video Player with "double" progress bar (video loaded/video play progress)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, progress-bar, flex3

I'm implementing an FLV video player based on Flex 3 and I would like to add a feature similar to YouTube player.

I want the progress bar to display both the video displaying progress, but also the video loaded status. How can I implement this behaviour?

Using 2 progress bars on top of each other? I'm also using Flex mx: VideoDisplay component, do I need to change this?

Comment: I think similar problem was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839310/flex-video-player-buffering

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thanks for reply. I understand now I really need 2 progress bars, one for the buffering process, and other for video display progress. How can I place then on top of each other now, so that they look like a single one?

Answer (score 1):

yes you should place two bars ontop of each other in the background you place the laodingbar and in the Front you place the current position bar.

But finally this is a bit more work than it looks to make it fully functional...
I would create a new class implementing all bar/slider functionality.

The laoder is only listening on update(val) to set its new value on percentage.
The playingbar will need some functionality on click and mousedown/mousemove for seeking AND the update function to be set again, including an event to trigger seek in the player aftern userinteraction.

Then you bind the loading bar update to the progress event of the player
All events can be found here

```
//setting up loadingbar
player.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,slider_update);


//function to update the slider
private function slider_update(E:ProgressEvent):void{
    var percentage:float = 0;
    if(E.bytesTotal != 0){
       E.bytesLoaded/E.bytesTotal
    }
    slider.update(percentage)
}
```

With the current playbar its allmost the same

```
//listens to statechanges of the player to handle updates for cur-pos

player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE, checkStatechange);

private function checkStatechange(E:VideoEvent):void{
    if(player.totalTime!=0){
        timeSlider.update(E.playheadTime/E.totalTime);
    };
```

continue with binds on click to set seek immediatly - to mouseDown and the move to make the scrolling on video possible...
actually for the seek with mousedown the mousemove should be listening on stage so the mouseUp otherwise the user has to stay on the loadingbar while seeking this is in most cases allmost impossible to handle ;)
-have fun 
    }

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you recommend any tutorial where I can see all the steps involved? Specially the double progress bar with slider.